# NSarray it is not working

Tags: iphone, nsarray

Here is some code

```
aSong.songDuration = currentElementValue;
NSLog(@"SD = %@",aSong.songDuration);         //   Here aSong.Duration is right
[viewController.songs addObject:aSong];
Music *bSong = [viewController.songs objectAtIndex:1]; // here bSong.Duration is null
NSLog(@"bSong = %@",bSong.songDuration);
```

I tried different objectAtIndex but all the time the value is null. Is something wrong?

thanks

Comment: Have you actually created your songs array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding an element to an empty mutable array, it has the index `0`:

```
Music *bSong = [viewController.songs objectAtIndex:0];
```

Of course that is assuming `songs` actually is a `NSMutableArray` (not an `NSArray`, which is immutable) and that `songs` exists.

Comment: songs is NSMutableArray and before i made songs alloc init so i exists for sure. i tried objectAtIndex:0 and it is still null

Comment: @Dmitriy: What do you get if you output all the objects in `songs`? Maybe you have already have added objects to it earlier.

Comment: @GeorgFritzshe when i output songs i've got NULL

Comment: I forgot to alloc viewController!  I add viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];  before
        viewController.songs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; and it is works fine. Thank you very much!